# Output page not rendered correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a page with some controls on it.  When I put "<% label.Text = "changed";%>" after the definition of Label, Label's text value is not rendered after the page is executed. Why?

```
<div>
   <tagprefix:MD ID="CC"  runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="TextBox1"/>
        <asp:Button Text="button" ID="Button"  runat="server" onclick="Button_Click" />
        <%= "Hello..." %>

        <% label.Text = "changed"; %>                          //working fine
        <asp:Label ID="label" Text="text" runat="server" />
        <% label.Text = "changed"; %>               // do not work
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string hello = "hello";

Response.Write( hello );

hello = "world"
```

Why does it display "hello" instead of "world" ?

The answer to that question is also the answer to yours.